# Manually installed, or, Installed manually

Tags: adverbs, word-order, adverb-placement

I'm curious to know if there is a difference with regard to the order of these words (especially when they are at the end of a sentence).

Comment: No difference in most contexts.  One might be preferred over the other depending on how used, though.

Answer (score 2):

Both forms are current usage in instruction manuals and owner guides though "manually installed" seems to be used more often.